# How to make sure in React, whether a list element has been viewed and if yes then take some action

Tags: list, events, reactjs, element

I have a scenario wherein using React, I am displaying a list of Notifications (each maximum 300 characters long) in a side pane window on a web page. (See attached pic)

I need to establish whether a notification has been viewed by the user or not. So that when a notification comes into user's view, it will raise an event to inform server via an Ajax call that it has been viewed.

Now I know that there are some presented solutions on different forums how to make sure whether a page element is in view or not.

But my concern and question is how to do that neatly and in a standardized way in ReactJS and much good if we go for it without using any jQuery approach?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dunno how you are rendering these elements. If whole notification (rows) are individual components, as @gyzerok mentioned simply add an AJAX call in componentDidMount (each row can have its own AJAX call so every will be mentioned, or whole notification box can have group AJAX that will send Notifications IDs or whatever in one call).

If they are on the other hand rendered before (and only hidden, it might be a bit more complex). Probably you would need to set an action on Clear All (cause when you are closing you can expect that someone saw notifications) or on Open notifications (you probably open them by some button aint you?).

So that would be my solution. The first one is more "clear" for me though.

**edit:**
For each row seperate (and checking if it is visible in the window) then you could also use a tool like 
[github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor](http://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor) 
or similar. It is tracking if the element is visible in the window (and then in onChange function you could write a function which would fire an AJAX

Comment: Consider each notification message as a row in a table. But yes... things get complex when that row is not at first visible to the user and the user has to scroll down the window to see the row.

Comment: then you could also use a tool like https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor or similar. It is tracking if the element is visible in the window (and then in onChange function you could write a function which would fire an AJAX

Comment: Excellent suggestion 'react-visibility-sensor'. I used it and yes it works like a charm. Please update this in your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Your component is actually should after it has been mounted to the DOM. So you may use componentDidMount lifecycle hook to know if component was actually presented to your user.